# Python 3 Print Variables

Tags: python, variables, printing

Is there a better way to print set of variable in python3 ?

In PHP I useally did something like this:
`echo "http://$username:$password@$server:$port"`

But in python 3 it looks very ugly and longer to type with all those +'s

`print('http://'+username+':'+password+'@'+server+':'+port)`

Is there something like this in python like "$" symbol ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't support string interpolation, but you can do it with string formatting:

```
'http://{}:{}@{}:{}'.format(username, password, server, port)
```

Or with keyword arguments (best used if you already have the arguments in a dictionary):

```
'http://{username}:{password}@{server}:{port}'.format(
    username=username,
    password=password,
    server=server,
    port=port
)
```

You could also abuse `locals()` a little, but I wouldn't suggest doing it this way:

```
'http://{username}:{password}@{server}:{port}'.format(**locals())
```

Comment: This is much better for some code :-) Thank you. But why you don't suggest locals() ? It seems like the cleanest way ^_^ I'm suprised that python did not include a better way for simple variables in double quotes LOL